# Remote control android from other app

Tags: android

I want to control a certain app on android from an app on a pc with these conditions.

- PC app will work alone so I can't depend on a human.
- PC app should be able manipulate the android app and fill forms.
- PC app should be able to know what data is displayed on device.
- Android app is a third party app that I can't change.
- I have full control of android device so root isn't a problem(probably will use an emulated android).

The purpose is to a pc app receive some data and fill it on android device without human interference.
The PC app probably will be ruby or node, but I can change if necessary.

Currently I can't find anything about how to "read" a third party app, just how to show the android screen on pc and how to send signals do android

Comment: Great. But what do you need or are stuck with?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Comment: How I do this? All that I find about remote control is to show the android screen on PC and send mouse/keyboard signals do android. I can't find anything about "reading" a third party app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that appium is exactly what I want. Thanks Owls